# Show div when link clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following portion of code.

I'd like to hide `sub-menu` originally and display if the link `Type` is clicked.
How do I do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/jk30af2a/

```
<div class="thirdy">
    <ul class="sf-menu" style="list-style-type:none">
        <li class="main"><a href="#">Type</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="/teams/" title="View all Teams" >Teams</a></li>
            <li><a href="/events/" title="View all Events" >Event</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click & http://api.jquery.com/show

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a click event on a element and toggle its next sibling in click handler:

```
$('.main a').click(function(){
   $(this).next().toggle()
}).click();//<-- for hiding the options by default on load
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/csv9abav/)**

Answer (score 1):

you code be something like this http://jsfiddle.net/elviz/045z9gdr/1/

```
$(".sub-menu").toggle();
     $(".main").click(function(){
       $(".sub-menu").toggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toggleClass()`

Jquery

```
 $(".main").click(function(){
    $(this).find($(".sub-menu")).toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

CSS

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/khanhvdv/jk30af2a/2/)